# strcmp files - Very large file size output

Tags: matlab, strcmp

I'm reading in a csv file that is about 80MB - `data_O3`. It's about 250,000 x 5 in size. I created `E`, which is a little bit larger because it has all the days (`data_O3` is missing some days). I want to compare the two so that if the date (saved in variable `d3`) and siteID (`d4`) are the same, the data point (column 5) is placed in `E`.

```
for j = 1:size(data_O3,1) 
    E(strcmp(d3,data_O3{j,3})&d4 == data_O3{j,4},5) = data_O3(j,5);
end
```

This script works fine, but for some reason, running it takes longer than expected. I've run the same code for other data that were only slightly smaller with no problem. Is this an issue with the `strcmp` code or something else?

The script and files used can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7bzq3m1ixfeuhu6/i4oOvxHPkn

Comment: `strcmp` returns a logical `0` or `1`, so it writes to either `E(0,5)` or `E(1,5)`... and '0' is not a valid index.

I don't think this code "works" as well as you think it does.

Comment: you can propagate `&d4` in the `strcmp` to save a bit?

Comment: @BenVoigt wouldn't it work via binary indexing?

Comment: @BenVoigt Nothing is wrong with `E(false,5)`, it just returns an empty matrix. Interestingly, you can use it as an lvalue, and it just does nothing in the assignment. Weird, huh?

Comment: I didn't realize you could mix logical and numeric indexing, but I just found a reference that says you can.

Comment: @BenVoigt At the risk of getting off topic, could you share the reference?

Comment: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/10/07/indexing-mixing-it-up/#9

Comment: Are `d3` and `d4` arrays?

Comment: OK. I will add a link with my code and one of the files.

Comment: Could you link `read_mixed_csv` function too?

Comment: Sorry. Added that file to the same folder

Comment: @Ben Voigt d3 and d4 are matrices - one column with the same number of rows as E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly see a number of ways to speed this up significantly.

First of all, read in all numeric data in as numbers.  Matlab is not optimized to work with strings, and even cells should generally be avoided as much as possible.  If you want to keep everything as strings, use another language (python or perl)

Once you have the state, county and site read in as numbers, then create a number instead of a string for the siteID.  One approach would be to use the formula:

```
siteID = siteNum + 1e4*countyCode + 1e7*stateCode
```

That would generate unique siteIDs for all sites.

Use datenum to convert the date field into a number.

You are now in a position where the `data_O3` defined on line 79 can be a purely numeric array (no cells!), as can your `E` matrix.  That alone will make the process many times faster.

You also might want to define the `E` as something other than NaN.  Maybe give it values of -1.

There may be more optimizations you can do in the comparison, but do the above first and I expect you will see a huge improvement.

Comment: Could you give more details? I'm actually still relatively unfamiliar with coding. I already have the dates as date numbers. It would be great if you can take a look at the files I posted and show how I would detect missing days. I need to match the SiteIDs as well as the date columns since the file has a bunch of different sites and each site has data for a year.

Comment: Didn't see the data when I started, so I made wrong assumptions.  I'll delete the answer for now.

Comment: I did everything you suggested, but it is still taking a long time. I don't know if it made much of a difference. Do you know why the output it so much larger than the 80MB file that is going into it?

Comment: can you save the data_O3 array and the E array in a mat file and provide those, and then provide the updated code?

Comment: I added the new script (`Readin_MDA8_O3_US_1990_2014_cell1.m`) and the .mat file with what you asked for to the dropbox link above. `data_O3_output.mat` is the mat file. `data_O3` is the cell and `data_O3_mat` is the all double matrix. `E` has all the columns filled in except for the last column, which is the data I'm trying to compare it to to fill in. As you can see, these files are not large at all. But starting in line 108 of the code (the `strcmp` part), the script gets super slow and the output becomes gigantic.

Comment: Oops. I figured out what was wrong. I had to change the range of the datenum.

Comment: I see.  I hope my pointers at least make it better for you to work with this and other problems.